# Use an Excel VBA Loop to search a data table and copy selected rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a workbook with a database that will go extend to 2k rows, to search quick I'm trying to write some VBAcode that will copy the complete row  from that sheet to a other one.

for example, I have type ERFJ06 in cell (G6)on sheet 1, I want the code go search that number in the database on sheet2, when the code found it it must copy that whole row with data to sheet 1 on B13:Y13.

I write this code as a dummy, but it wont report the data, when I debug it, for some reason I don't get error´s, anyone see what's wrong?

```
Sub search()



Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim Material As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Set datasheet = Sheet8
Set reportsheet = Sheet4
Seq = reportsheet.Range("G6").Value


reportsheet.Range("b13:w13").ClearContents


datasheet.Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For a = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(a, 1) = Material Then
        Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 12)).Copy
        reportsheet.Select
        Range("a200").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        datasheet.Select
        End If
Next a

reportsheet.Select

Range("G6").Select

End Sub
```

regards,
Niels

Comment: You find the last row and store it in the `lRow` variable, but then use `finalRow` in your loop.  If you go to Tools > Options and select _Require Variable Declaration_ you won't be able to use variables you haven't declared first.

Comment: `Material ` is empty. You never assign a value to it

Comment: side note: The screen will flicker as it switches back and forth between sheets. To avoid this, dont use Sheets.Select and instead just fully reference the ranges with `reportsheet.Range` or `datasheet.Range`.